# How to read data from a branch in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

im trying to get the "type" value here (see the image)
[image]

and here is what im doing

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email , password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
           DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user type").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
           
        }
    }
});
```

but i don't know what todo further.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

`DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("usertype").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("type");`

Comment: then i have to use "reference.addValueEventListener" to get the value, am i right? or is there any other way to directly access the value without attaching the listener

Comment: yes u need to attach a listener ! You can also use a query, but that is just another way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

i did this and it worked

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email , password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user type").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                   reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                           String temp = snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString();
                           Log.d("hereIm","temp == "+temp);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                       }
                   });
                }
            }
        });
```